# Unable to build id3lib on Crunchbang

Tags: debian, software-installation, compiling

I'm trying to install `id3lib` in my new Crunchbang distro. So, I downloaded the tar.gz file and executed `configure` command which ran good. And when I run `make` I'm getting the following error:

```
make[2]: *** [c_wrapper.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've also added the full output below for reference.

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3'
Making all in m4
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/m4'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/m4'
Making all in zlib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib'
cd . \
      && CONFIG_FILES= CONFIG_HEADERS=config.h \
         /bin/bash ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing default-1 commands
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib'
Making all in include
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/include'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/include'
Making all in src
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/src'
source='adler32.c' object='adler32.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/adler32.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/adler32.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o adler32.lo `test -f adler32.c || echo './'`adler32.c
mkdir .libs
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c adler32.c -MT adler32.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/adler32.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/adler32.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c adler32.c -MT adler32.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/adler32.TPlo -o adler32.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/adler32.lo adler32.lo
source='compress.c' object='compress.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/compress.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/compress.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o compress.lo `test -f compress.c || echo './'`compress.c
rm -f .libs/compress.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c compress.c -MT compress.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/compress.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/compress.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c compress.c -MT compress.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/compress.TPlo -o compress.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/compress.lo compress.lo
source='crc32.c' object='crc32.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/crc32.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/crc32.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o crc32.lo `test -f crc32.c || echo './'`crc32.c
rm -f .libs/crc32.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c crc32.c -MT crc32.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/crc32.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/crc32.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c crc32.c -MT crc32.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/crc32.TPlo -o crc32.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/crc32.lo crc32.lo
source='deflate.c' object='deflate.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/deflate.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/deflate.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o deflate.lo `test -f deflate.c || echo './'`deflate.c
rm -f .libs/deflate.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c deflate.c -MT deflate.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/deflate.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/deflate.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c deflate.c -MT deflate.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/deflate.TPlo -o deflate.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/deflate.lo deflate.lo
source='gzio.c' object='gzio.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/gzio.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/gzio.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o gzio.lo `test -f gzio.c || echo './'`gzio.c
rm -f .libs/gzio.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c gzio.c -MT gzio.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gzio.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/gzio.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c gzio.c -MT gzio.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gzio.TPlo -o gzio.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/gzio.lo gzio.lo
source='infblock.c' object='infblock.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/infblock.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/infblock.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o infblock.lo `test -f infblock.c || echo './'`infblock.c
rm -f .libs/infblock.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c infblock.c -MT infblock.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/infblock.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/infblock.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c infblock.c -MT infblock.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/infblock.TPlo -o infblock.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/infblock.lo infblock.lo
source='infcodes.c' object='infcodes.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/infcodes.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/infcodes.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o infcodes.lo `test -f infcodes.c || echo './'`infcodes.c
rm -f .libs/infcodes.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c infcodes.c -MT infcodes.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/infcodes.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/infcodes.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c infcodes.c -MT infcodes.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/infcodes.TPlo -o infcodes.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/infcodes.lo infcodes.lo
source='inffast.c' object='inffast.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/inffast.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/inffast.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o inffast.lo `test -f inffast.c || echo './'`inffast.c
rm -f .libs/inffast.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c inffast.c -MT inffast.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/inffast.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/inffast.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c inffast.c -MT inffast.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/inffast.TPlo -o inffast.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/inffast.lo inffast.lo
source='inflate.c' object='inflate.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/inflate.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/inflate.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o inflate.lo `test -f inflate.c || echo './'`inflate.c
rm -f .libs/inflate.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c inflate.c -MT inflate.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/inflate.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/inflate.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c inflate.c -MT inflate.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/inflate.TPlo -o inflate.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/inflate.lo inflate.lo
source='inftrees.c' object='inftrees.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/inftrees.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/inftrees.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o inftrees.lo `test -f inftrees.c || echo './'`inftrees.c
rm -f .libs/inftrees.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c inftrees.c -MT inftrees.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/inftrees.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/inftrees.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c inftrees.c -MT inftrees.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/inftrees.TPlo -o inftrees.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/inftrees.lo inftrees.lo
source='infutil.c' object='infutil.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/infutil.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/infutil.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o infutil.lo `test -f infutil.c || echo './'`infutil.c
rm -f .libs/infutil.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c infutil.c -MT infutil.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/infutil.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/infutil.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c infutil.c -MT infutil.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/infutil.TPlo -o infutil.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/infutil.lo infutil.lo
source='trees.c' object='trees.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/trees.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/trees.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o trees.lo `test -f trees.c || echo './'`trees.c
rm -f .libs/trees.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c trees.c -MT trees.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/trees.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/trees.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c trees.c -MT trees.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/trees.TPlo -o trees.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/trees.lo trees.lo
source='uncompr.c' object='uncompr.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/uncompr.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/uncompr.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o uncompr.lo `test -f uncompr.c || echo './'`uncompr.c
rm -f .libs/uncompr.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c uncompr.c -MT uncompr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/uncompr.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/uncompr.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c uncompr.c -MT uncompr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/uncompr.TPlo -o uncompr.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/uncompr.lo uncompr.lo
source='zutil.c' object='zutil.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/zutil.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/zutil.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include    -g -O2 -c -o zutil.lo `test -f zutil.c || echo './'`zutil.c
rm -f .libs/zutil.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c zutil.c -MT zutil.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zutil.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/zutil.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -c zutil.c -MT zutil.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zutil.TPlo -o zutil.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .libs/zutil.lo zutil.lo
/bin/bash ../libtool --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o libz.la -rpath /usr/local/lib -version-info 1:0:0 adler32.lo compress.lo crc32.lo deflate.lo gzio.lo infblock.lo infcodes.lo inffast.lo inflate.lo inftrees.lo infutil.lo trees.lo uncompr.lo zutil.lo  
rm -fr .libs/libz.la .libs/libz.* .libs/libz.*
gcc -shared  adler32.lo compress.lo crc32.lo deflate.lo gzio.lo infblock.lo infcodes.lo inffast.lo inflate.lo inftrees.lo infutil.lo trees.lo uncompr.lo zutil.lo   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libz.so.1 -o .libs/libz.so.1.0.0
(cd .libs && rm -f libz.so.1 && ln -s libz.so.1.0.0 libz.so.1)
(cd .libs && rm -f libz.so && ln -s libz.so.1.0.0 libz.so)
ar cru .libs/libz.a  adler32.o compress.o crc32.o deflate.o gzio.o infblock.o infcodes.o inffast.o inflate.o inftrees.o infutil.o trees.o uncompr.o zutil.o 
ranlib .libs/libz.a
creating libz.la
(cd .libs && rm -f libz.la && ln -s ../libz.la libz.la)
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/src'
Making all in lib
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/lib'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/lib'
Making all in prj
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/prj'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib/prj'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/zlib'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/doc'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/include'
Making all in id3
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/include/id3'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/include'
Making all in id3com
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/id3com'
Making all in Sample
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/id3com/Sample'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/id3com/Sample'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/id3com'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/id3com'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/id3com'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/src'
source='c_wrapper.cpp' object='c_wrapper.lo' libtool=yes \
    depfile='.deps/c_wrapper.Plo' tmpdepfile='.deps/c_wrapper.TPlo' \
    depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include/id3 -I../include -I../zlib/include    -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-inline -Woverloaded-virtual -Wmissing-declarations  -c -o c_wrapper.lo `test -f 'c_wrapper.cpp' || echo './'`c_wrapper.cpp
mkdir .libs
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../include/id3 -I../include -I../zlib/include -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -Wno-inline -Woverloaded-virtual -Wmissing-declarations -c c_wrapper.cpp -MT c_wrapper.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/c_wrapper.TPlo  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/c_wrapper.lo
In file included from ../include/id3/utils.h:37:0,
                 from ../include/id3/tag.h:34,
                 from c_wrapper.cpp:30:
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h: In static member function 'static std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type* std::char_traits<unsigned char>::move(std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type*, const char_type*, std::size_t)':
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h:87:72: error: 'memmove' was not declared in this scope
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h: In static member function 'static std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type* std::char_traits<unsigned char>::copy(std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type*, const char_type*, std::size_t)':
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h:91:71: error: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope
c_wrapper.cpp: In function 'void ID3TagIterator_Delete(ID3TagIterator*)':
c_wrapper.cpp:350:7: warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'ID3_Tag::Iterator' which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
c_wrapper.cpp: In function 'void ID3TagConstIterator_Delete(ID3TagConstIterator*)':
c_wrapper.cpp:370:7: warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'ID3_Tag::ConstIterator' which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
make[2]: *** [c_wrapper.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gts/downloads/id3lib-3.8.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: This is where I politely enquire why you aren't using your distributions binary package.

Answer (score 0):

```
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h: In static member function 'static std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type* std::char_traits<unsigned char>::move(std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type*, const char_type*, std::size_t)':
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h:87:72: error: 'memmove' was not declared in this scope
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h: In static member function 'static std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type* std::char_traits<unsigned char>::copy(std::char_traits<unsigned char>::char_type*, const char_type*, std::size_t)':
../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h:91:71: error: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope
```

Open the `../include/id3/id3lib_strings.h` file and add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

or

```
#include <cstring>
```

Have a look here: [Compiler error: memset was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506036/3857510)